# Returns value of checkbox

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.net is the following code right ?

```
Dim r1 As Bollean = rd1.checked
```

checkbox returns what type of value?

then when I put this following code---

```
If Request.QueryString("r3") Then
     myReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Gradewise.rpt"))
End If'
```

It gives following error--

Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Checked` property of `checkbox` to get the checked status of checkbox. rd1.checkbox would return `object` of type `CheckBox`

```
Dim r1 As Bollean = rd1.checkbox.Checked
```

**Edit** as OP is edited. You have to give expression that results in boolean in if statement.

```
If Request.QueryString("r3") == "somevalue" Then
     myReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("Gradewise.rpt"))
End If'
```

Answer (score 0):

.checked property returns a boolean value.

And regarding error that you are getting - you are trying to put a string in a if statement while a condition which returns either true or false is expected.

So it should be

```
'If Request.QueryString("r3")="some string to compare" Then ...
```

as Request.QueryString("r3") returns a String!